# .NET MVC - Data not loading first time form is submitted, but loading instantly the second time the form is submitted

Tags: .net

I have an .NET MVC website that has a view with a form where the user selects a date range (I am not using ajax). When the user clicks submit, data is pasted to the controller and then the data pulled from an SQL database and displayed in another view. There is a loader that displays while the data is pulling.

The issue I am having is that the first time the user submits the form, the loader displays, but the data never loads (the user has waited up to an hour). When the user goes back to the view with the form and resubmits the same information, the data then loads instantly. The second request happens instantly regardless of how long the user waited for the first request. I also had the users clear their cache. This occurs in both IE and Chrome.

Does anyone know why this is occurring and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is the loader a custom visualization or the built-in wait cursor? What do the network requests look like in the browser's debugger? Have you tried debugging the server-side code? Do you have any JavaScript running on the page? Are there errors on the console? ...

Comment: The loader is a custom visualization (from Kendo UI). When I inspect the page in IE I see that the "received" column has a value of ~500 B and the associated "Taken" column has a value between 45 ms and 90 ms. The Initiator is JS Library XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I have debugged the server side code an no exceptions or errors are occur. The breakpoint were the sql query is being executed in the database is where I am seeing the stall

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is an AJAX request.

Comment: If you remove the loader widget does the page load normally? If so, you know where to start debugging.